# For Handling a CSV file in Python, How Can I write a row with multiple columns and not have it either turn into letters or wind up in a single column?

Tags: python, csv

This is using Python 3.

So, this code worked just fine (note I've changed filenames before posting it here). I'm running this on a very large file, so turning the reader into a list is not an option.

```
import csv

with open("file.csv", 'r') as q:
with open("file2.csv", 'w+', newline='') as w:
    qreader = csv.reader(q, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    i=0
    for row in qreader:
        if i == 0:
            header = ['ID', 'Number', 'Address', 'City', 'County Code', 'County', 'Zip']
            writer.writerow(header)
            i += 1
        else:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

This worked fine. All I did here was fix the header and otherwise keep the file exactly the same.

Then I tried this to split the file up so I could manipulate the parts in excel and in a way that is alphabetically in order and avoids splitting records on the same street (hence why I am splitting it by the first letter of the address).

```
import csv

with open("readfile.csv", 'r') as r, open("writefile1.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v1, open("writefile2.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v2, open("writefile3", 'w+', newline='') as v3, open("writefile4.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v4, open ("writefile5.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v5, open ("writefile6.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v6, open ("writefile7.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v7, open ("writefile8.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v8:
    reader = csv.reader(r)
    writerv1 = csv.writer(v1)
    writerv2 = csv.writer(v2)
    writerv3 = csv.writer(v3)
    writerv4 = csv.writer(v4)
    writerv5 = csv.writer(v5)
    writerv6 = csv.writer(v6)
    writerv7 = csv.writer(v7)
    writerv8 = csv.writer(v8)
for row in r:
    if i == 0:
        nrow.append(row)
        writerv1.writerow([row])
        writerv2.writerow([row])
        writerv3.writerow([row])
        writerv4.writerow([row])
        writerv5.writerow([row])
        writerv6.writerow([row])
        writerv7.writerow([row])
        writerv8.writerow([row])
        i += 1
    else:
        try:
            if row[2][0]<='B':
                writerv1.writerow([row])
            elif row[2][0]<='D':
                writerv2.writerow([row])
            elif row[2][0]<='G':
                writerv3.writerow([row])
            elif row[2][0] <= 'L':
                writerv4.writerow([row])
            elif row[2][0] <= 'O':
                writerv5.writerow([row])
            elif row[2][0] <= 'R':
                writerv6.writerow([row])
            elif row[2][0] <= 'U':
                writerv7.writerow([row])
            else:
                writerv8.writerow([row])
        except:
            writerv1.writerow([row])
```

If I don't have the rows in [] it outputs a letter for every column. If I put the rows in [] it puts every column in the first column separated by commas!

I don't understand why I didn't have a problem with the first code and now I am having a problem. I don't notice any differences.

From running a few tests I notice that row.split(',') does NOT output the row as a list when printed. So I've tried almost everything here.

EDIT: I should mention I started csv.reader with the delimiter=',' in there. I had thought that would guarantee the row would be read as a list. I took it away when it didn't seem to make a difference.

EDIT: Answered my own question. Should have mentioned that I was also having trouble putting the data into the right volumes. It was all going into the first written file and none of the others. After creating the `nrow` list for each instance of the loop I had to change the conditional statements to `nrow[2][0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're iterating over the input file and not the csv reader.

Try changing `for row in r` to `for row in reader` and remove the square brackets around all occurrences of `row` thereafter. Rows from `reader` should handle all splitting, stripping and newline issues too.

Comment: Thanks James. The more complicated solution I mentioned in my answer worked too, but then I noticed using ``list(row.strip().split(','))`` strangely not working and it said ``row`` was a ``list``. Now I know why. I had used ``reader`` in the one where the list method wasn't working, and ``r`` from ``with open``... ``as r`` in the case where I had to create a ``list``. Yours is a much neater solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open("readfile.csv", 'r') as r, open("writefile1.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v1, open("writefile2.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v2, open("writefile3.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v3, open("writefile4.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v4, open ("writefile5.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v5, open ("writefile6.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v6, open ("writefile7.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v7, open ("writefile8.csv", 'w+', newline='') as v8:

reader = csv.reader(r)
writerv1 = csv.writer(v1)
writerv2 = csv.writer(v2)
writerv3 = csv.writer(v3)
writerv4 = csv.writer(v4)
writerv5 = csv.writer(v5)
writerv6 = csv.writer(v6)
writerv7 = csv.writer(v7)
writerv8 = csv.writer(v8)
i = 0
for row in r:
    nrow = list(row.strip().split(','))
    if i == 0:
        writerv1.writerow(nrow)
        writerv2.writerow(nrow)
        writerv3.writerow(nrow)
        writerv4.writerow(nrow)
        writerv5.writerow(nrow)
        writerv6.writerow(nrow)
        writerv7.writerow(nrow)
        writerv8.writerow(nrow)
        i += 1
    else:
        try:
            if nrow[2][0]<='B':
                writerv1.writerow(nrow)
            elif nrow[2][0]<='D':
                writerv2.writerow(nrow)
            elif nrow[2][0]<='G':
                writerv3.writerow(nrow)
            elif nrow[2][0] <= 'L':
                writerv4.writerow(nrow)
            elif nrow[2][0] <= 'O':
                writerv5.writerow(nrow)
            elif nrow[2][0] <= 'R':
                writerv6.writerow(nrow)
            elif nrow[2][0] <= 'U':
                writerv7.writerow(nrow)
            else:
                writerv8.writerow(nrow)
        except:
            writerv1.writerow(nrow)
```

Hadn't realized that in addition to using strip I needed to put it into "list()" like so `nrow = list(row.strip().split(','))`. Since the last column heading fell off in my first attempt and it printed out "\n" at the end I added .strip() to eliminate whitespace.

I hadn't mentioned it at first since I was so focused on solving the issue of everything falling into the same column, but another issue was that all data except the header was going to the same file. I can see why now. I also had to change the conditions to reference`nrow[2][0]`, my new list (with the corresponding element and the first character of that element) instead of referencing `row[2][0]`.